# Is it OK to integrate changes into release branch?

Tags: git, git-flow

As it can be seen on this diagram, it's perfectly ok to merge bugfix changes made in a release branch into the develop branch before finishing it.

My question is, would it be OK to merge changes made in develop into a not finished feature? (red arrow, added by me) If so, which command/options would you recommend for it?

[image: Git Flow chart]

EDIT: The idea isn't necessarily to cherry-pick a commit. 
Since a feature branch can span across major version releases (like the left one on the diagram), my idea idea behind the merge is taking develop changes (like service or classes renames) into account in the feature branch in order to prevent (or start resolving) future merge conflicts that will come when release is finished, which could leave develop really unstable until solved.

Answer (score 2):

As to your question "would it be okay", I think it depends. It's possible that A is stable while D is unknown. To merge D into feature may introduce some side effect or bug. If the bug slows down your work on feature, you may prefer not to merge. If you think it's important to find out the potential bugs as soon as possible, it's okay to merge.

```
A--B--C-D-E-F->dev
 \  
  M-N-O--P->feature
```

Suppose you want to merge D to feature. If you want D only, excluding B and C, `git checkout feature;git cherry-pick D`. If you want B C D, `git checkout feature;git merge D` or `git rebase --onto D A feature`. git-rebase creates a tidier history while git-merge back and forth may create a complex commit graph in the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The idea *isn't to cherry-pick* a commit. The idea behind the merge is taking develop changes or renames into account in the feature branch in order to *prevent* (or start resolving) *future merge* conflicts when release is finished, which could leave develop really unstable until solved. :)